# Css transform + transition резко обрывается анимация

Tags: css, анимация, transition, transform

Почему дергается анимация? Когда навести курсор, потом убрать, дождаться пока анимация вернется на начальную позицию и резко опять навести курсор, то анимация начинается как бы не с начала. Это срабатывает не всегда, потому наводить придется раз 50 )) Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Это будет иконка меню-бургер складывающаяся (к примеру в крест) при наведении.
Знаю что проблема легко решается на jquery, но хотелось бы выяснить почему так происходит.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:grey;
    margin:80px;
}
.line{
    width:100%;
    height:8px;
    background-color:black;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
.container:hover .line{
    transition: 1s linear;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

тут пример https://jsfiddle.net/vm12aa1w/

тут задавал вопрос но решения так и не нашел, в комментариях к первому ответу человек выложил видео(отдельное ему спасибо) в котором видно как анимация резко соскакивает на начало  https://otvet.mail.ru/question/183027834

Comment: В текущей версии хрома (49) проблемы нет?

Answer (score 2):

1. У меня всё плавно.
2. Не стоит писать `transition` внутри `:hover`. Вместо этого надо писать `transition` для самого элемента, а на `:hover` просто менять нужные свойства. Я уже сталкивался с тем, что при прописывании `transition` в `:hover` наблюдаются скачки - вероятно, оно срабатывает не мгновенно, а как получится, после чего пересчитывается стадия анимации за всё прошедшее время.

Comment: 1. Значит мало наводили туда-сюда ) 2. Если убрать transition из :hover, то скачки становятся еще больше. Я тоже так думал что transform срабатывает быстрее transition. Из-за этого некоторый участок анимации проскакивает.

Comment: @Ростислав, да, понял... Воспроизводится.

Comment: @Ростислав, такое ощущение, что оно с наведением на саму линию связано.

Comment: попробовал только что наводить только на квадрат, возможно меньше, но все равно есть скачки. Вы не знаете случайно как отладить анимацию, посмотреть ее ход? К примеру в хроме что-то есть в инструментах разработчика для анимации, но я не знаю то ли это. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Ростислав, не отлаживал. К счастью, всё работало.

Comment: Жаль. Но все равно спасибо за помощь. Возможно найдется кто-то сталкивающийся с этой проблемой в лоб)

Comment: @Ростислав, https://jsfiddle.net/vm12aa1w/1/ - кажется, лучше, но всё равно глючит...

Comment: Да, чуть лучше. Решил попробовать переместить  `transition` за transform/в начало класса так анимация вообще начала прыгать почти на 100%. Походу еще и позиция имеет значение.